# PHP if condition with and and or

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this condition here:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/page.php' || ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/index.php')){

        //do something, but not on index or page . php

}
```

it works on the index page, but not page.php...what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Probably the way you have your brackets setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it easier...

```
if( ! in_array( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], array("/page.php", "/", "/index.php") ) ) {
  // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have logical error use

```
if(!($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/page.php' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php')){

        //do something, but not on index or page . php
}
```

or better

```
if(!in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ["/page.php", "/", "/index.php"])){

        //do something, but not on index or page . php
}
```